# PHP - how to implement variable into adress

Tags: php, variables

I am learning PHP and on my index page I have form in which you put a name and then it redirects you back to index.php and there it picks the variable and gives you some welcome message, depending on the name plus everyone gets some text (which is the same for everyone).

And my problems arises, when I want to make a menu, there are other pages (lets say some history, members, etc ...). In this menu I want have some redirection back to the first page, but with the same welcome message without having to type in the name again. Is it possible (not necessarily by PHP)? I would normally do that using javascript file put in the page, but I would have to input the name again ...

EDIT 1 - Thanks to your answers, I started learning about SESSIONS. Could you please tell me what I have made bad on this script? It keeps me getting this error "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /var/www/php/index.php:16) in /var/www/php/index.php on line 17
cau johnny"

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Nora</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Johnny KliÄŤka">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css">
    <style>
    p {font-size: 50px; text-align: center}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    if($_SESSION['name'] = "Johnny"){
    echo "cau johnny";
    } else if($_SESSION['name'] = "Naty"){
        echo "cau naty";
    } else {
        echo "neznam";
    }
}
?>


</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Learn about session variables.

Comment: If you're learning PHP then it's now time to learn something about [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using PHP sessions.

You will need to save the user's name in a session variable, for example `$_SESSION['name']`.
Then you can use `echo $_SESSION['name']` to output the user's name.

You need to remember to initiate sessions at the top of your PHP script using `session_start()`.